# Budgie - Panel, Dock mode; customization, modification

Tags: themes, panel, gtk3, budgie

Please, is it possible to modify the corners of the panel in dock mode, but only the dock, keeping a top panel straight? Themes like Mojave or Plata seem to have this. If I create a gtk.css (with something like: .budgie-panel.left{border-radius:5px}) and save on /.config/gtk-3.0/ that will modify every panel. Trying to make round corners on Adapta-nokto-eta. Thanks. (OS: Solus 4.3 Fortitude; Budgie 10.6.2). [image: Adapta-nokto-eta dock mode straight corners]

Comment: It may help if you provided your OS/release details; as they provide details as to your software stack (budgie version, library versions etc)

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: O! I apologize for posting a question here, but smaller communities (though all respect to them) can take a while to reach someone with an answer for something that is not a bug  or a problem but an aesthetic peculiarity of some random useless user who's a bit too curious. People here seem more forgiving of such an user... Again, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is OK. I've done in a, probably (because I don't know anything about anything), crude fashion by creating a file: /.config/gtk-3.0/.gtk.css

```
.budgie-panel {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: rgba(34, 45, 50, 0.9);
}
```

.top .budgie-panel.dock-mode { border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px; }

.bottom .budgie-panel.dock-mode { border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0; }

.left .budgie-panel.dock-mode { border-radius: 0 7px 7px 0; }

.right .budgie-panel.dock-mode { border-radius: 7px 0 0 7px; }

Added some transparency as well. I Think it looks alright (I just don't know if is going to break something in the future...).

[image]